# ParseObject Not saved to Dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

I just started to implement parse in my app. 
I want to save user data on a cloud so it can be accessed by other users. 
I'm trying to subclass the ParseObject just as they guide in their tutorial. 
I can see on the dashboard the new class i created, but no object is being uploaded there.

same thing about the exampleObject.

this is the Application Class onCreate():

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(MyClass.class);
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "YYYY");

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Object");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();

    MyClass R = new MyClass();
    R.set(...) //here i set all attributes
    ArrayList<Ingredient> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    R.saveInBackground();
```

MyClass:

```
@ParseClassName("MyClass")
public class MyClass extends ParseObject implements Serializable , Cloneable{

private attrs; //define Class's attributes

public MyClass()
{
    super();
}
```

I added the uses-permissions and gradle code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using R.set() to set the attributes but there is no set method for ParseObjects and I don't see one in MyClass().

Try using R.put(key, value) to add data to the object.

From Parse.com:

"You can add accessors and mutators for the fields of your ParseObject easily. Declare the getter and setter for the field as you normally would, but implement them in terms of get() and put(). The following example creates a displayName field in the Armor class:"

```
// Armor.java
@ParseClassName("Armor")
public class Armor extends ParseObject {
  public String getDisplayName() {
    return getString("displayName");
  }
  public void setDisplayName(String value) {
    put("displayName", value);
  }
}
```

Comment: from what i understand in their tutorial it should work this way.. 

"Subclassing is completely optional, but can transform this code:"

    ParseObject shield = new ParseObject("Armor");
    shield.put("displayName", "Wooden Shield");
    shield.put("fireproof", false);
    shield.put("rupees", 50);

 Into this:

    Armor shield = new Armor();
    shield.setDisplayName("Wooden Shield");
    shield.setFireproof(false);
    shield.setRupees(50);

Comment: Yes you can use the methods setDisplayName(), setFireproof(), setRupees(), but you would need to define these methods in your new class using the put method. Check updated answer.

Comment: That was probably part of the problem, but i still can't even see the simple test objects.. there must be some other problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking then. The above code should work if you want to create a custom Parse Object.